# Segmentation Fault when using vtkPolyLine in custom Paraview Filter

Tags: c++, 3d, segmentation-fault, vtk, paraview

I want to display multiple sets of 3D points using vtkPolyLine. 
The points are stored as Nodes(custom class) in a multidimensional vector:
    `vector<vector <Node> > criticalLines;` where a node has: `double posX; double posY; double posZ;` to store its position.

For the following section I tried to use vtkPolyLine similar to this example: 
http://www.paraview.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/GeometricObjects/PolyLine

This function is called after the vector has been filled with nodes:

```
void Algorithm::displayLines(vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints> points,vtkSmartPointer<vtkCellArray> lines)
{
for(int i = 0; i<criticalLines.size(); i++)
{
    if(criticalLines[i].empty())
    {
        continue;
    }

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyLine> polyLine =
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyLine>::New()

    for(int j =0; j< criticalLines[i].size(); ++j)
    {

        vtkIdType idx=points->InsertNextPoint(criticalLines[i][j].posX,
                      criticalLines[i][j].posY,
                      criticalLines[i][j].posZ);
        //print posX,posY,posZ of current Node
        criticalLines[i][j].PrintSelf();


        //Seg. Fault occurs here 
        polyLine->GetPointIds()->SetId(j,idx);


    }
    lines->InsertNextCell(polyLine);

}

}
```

Both `points` and `lines` are defined in Algorithm.h file and initialized in the constructor as follows:

```
points = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints>::New();
lines = vtkSmartPointer<vtkCellArray>::New();
```

And added to `vtkPolyData` later on:

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData> opd=vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData>::New() ;
opd->SetPoints(algorithm.points);
opd->SetLines(algorithm.lines);
```

Output of`criticalLines[i][j].PrintSelf();` shows values as expected.

When using `vtkSmartPointer<vtkTriangle> triangle = vtkSmartPointer<vtkTriangle>::New();` instead of `vtkPolyLine` everything works fine.

The solution to this [create multiple polylines given a set of points using vtk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25782105/create-multiple-polylines-given-a-set-of-points-using-vtk) somehow related problem did not seem to be what I was looking for.

I am not sure what is missing/wrong in my Code.
Please let me know if you need more information.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `vtkPolyLine` needs to allocate some space for the point IDs, like

```
polyLine->GetPointIds()->SetNumberOfIds(5);
```

in the example you linked to. In your case, you need to call

```
polyLine->GetPointIds()->SetNumberOfIds(criticalLines[i].size());
```

right after creating `polyLine`.

Comment: Thank you!I totally missed that.